# How can I pass nested parameter value to service in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, service, parameters, dependency-injection

For example, in my *services.yml* file next code:

```
parameters:
    social:
        facebook:
            app_id: 123456789
            secret: dkl41a5dw1daw11d1wa135451awwlflaw
        google:
            id: 12548411654

services:
    bw.user.social:
        class: BW\UserBundle\Service\SocialService
        arguments: [%social.facebook%]
```

This method does not work. I can use this:

```
services:
    bw.user.social:
        class: BW\UserBundle\Service\SocialService
        arguments: [%social%]
```

But it's not exactly what I need. How can I pass **only** facebook value without google and , it's very important, **not change** parameters structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write your parameters like this :

```
parameters:
    social.facebook:
        app_id: 123456789
        secret: dkl41a5dw1daw11d1wa135451awwlflaw
    social.google:
        id: 12548411654
```

Then you can use :

```
services:
    bw.user.social:
        class: BW\UserBundle\Service\SocialService
        arguments: [%social.facebook%]
```

Comment: Yes, it's work, but the parameters structure **is changed**. And without changing the structure can not be done?

Comment: You cannot use a "tree-browsing syntax" to get some sub-parameters. All parameters have to be on the first level because each parameter is supposed to be a injected dependance. Using sub-level parameters injection would be like inject "half-dependencies", so it's impossible.