# accessing array elements in symfony2 service container

Tags: symfony, service, parameter-passing

I'll explain with a simple example.this is the services.yml file:

```
parameters:
    foo.array:
        bar: barstring
        baz: bazstring

services:
    bar_service:
        class: barclass
        arguments:
            - # i want to give foo.array['bar'] (barstring) here as an argument
```

how do i do that?

Comment: I've tried %foo.array.bar% and %foo.array["bar"]% but none of them work.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that you can. You could set `barstring` as it's own parameter and then reference that as `bar: %barstring%` to stop repetition and also keep the array but I'm not sure the other way is possible...... In fact this has been covered, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19920871/1791606

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. The parameter must be at first level.

in your example, you could do:

```
parameters:
    foo.array.bar: barstring
    foo.array.baz: bazstring

services:
    bar_service:
        class: barclass
        arguments:
            - %foo.array.bar%
```

Duplicate of [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21092114/1237989)